# how to remove HTML parameters in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

by default, my `<button>` has a `disabled="disabled"` value in my HTML markup.
which makes the `<button>` **non-clickable**

```
<button id="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" disabled="disabled" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

if the `<textarea>` is more than 30 characters, it will remove the parameter `disabled` and make the button **clickable**

Im not sure how to  remove or even add parameters inside an html markup using jquery.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){

$j("#textField").keyup(function(){
    num = $j(this);
    if ($j(this).val().length >= 30 ) {
        $j("#charNum").text(30-num.val().length);
        $j('#submit") // disable
    }
    else {
           $j("#submit") // enable
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.removeAttr()` method.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){

$j("#textField").keyup(function(){
    num = $j(this);
    if ($j(this).val().length >= 30 ) {
        $j("#charNum").text(30-num.val().length);
        $j("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else {
           $j("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To disable you can use

```
 $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
```

To enable you can use

```
$("#submit").button( "enable" );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .prop()

```
$j('#submit').prop('disabled',false); // Enable the button
$j('#submit').prop('disabled',true); // Disable the button
```

For other you can use .removeAttr() to remove an attribute from an html element, but for checked, disabled, you'd better use .prop()

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
if ($j(this).val().length >= 30) {
    $j('#submit').prop('disabled', true);   // disable
} else {
    $j('#submit').prop('disabled', false);  // enable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The solution for the question raised by you is solved and [**refer the linkdemo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PXyvL/)

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){

$j("#textField").keyup(function(){
num = $j(this);
if ($j(this).val().length >= 30 ) {
    $j("#charNum").text(30-num.val().length);
    $j("#submit").prop('disabled', false); // disable
}
else {
       $j("#submit").prop('disabled',true) // enable
}

});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)/[removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) methods

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){

$j("#textField").keyup(function(){
    num = $j(this);
    if ($j(this).val().length >= 30 ) {
        $j("#charNum").text(30-num.val().length);
        $j('#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else {
           $j("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
           //$j("#submit").attr('disabled',''); //Same functionality
    }

});
});
```